# Dual boot windows Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I can't set boot on ubuntu. I tried many things unsuccesfully...

Here is my boot-info :
[https://framabin.org/p/?7a1d081105d818ab#IUzTtgYP1u+t9whjEXUIhbg17r63K0MrAFOqnWXlhZg=](https://framabin.org/p/?7a1d081105d818ab#IUzTtgYP1u%20t9whjEXUIhbg17r63K0MrAFOqnWXlhZg=)

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Can't check your boot info, it asks for a password.

Comment: Is it better like this ?
https://framabin.org/p/?621bd9ae5d1eda1b#e+LFfgBGasKoLFhJZwHxROR1DrPUAIHnyBBRLaAaT2A=